# Missing "./react" export in "zustand" package

Tags: reactjs, vite, zustand

Currently when I try to use any sort of Zustand state, even from the docs, I get an error saying `Missing "./react" export in "zustand" package`. I am using Vite and TypeScript.

```
const bears = useBearStore((state) => state.bears);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(bears);
  }, []);
```

Here is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import * as path from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') }],
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your import. It should be:

```js
import create from 'zustand';
```